# WSDL file for Apache CXF with "any xml" body

Tags: soap, wsdl, cxf

Background: I'm developing web-service which communicates over WS-Management protocol. The original WSDL from here http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/06/management/wsman.wsdl looks like:

```
<xs:complexType name="SampleResourceType">
  <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="PropertyA" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:element name="PropertyB" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="SampleResource" type="tns:SampleResourceType"/>

<wsdl:message name="PutMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:SampleResource"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

And this WSDL works well with Apache CXF 2.4.0.

My goal:
Replace SampleResource definition with other to let operation handle any resource(XML). I'd like to create WSDL file for operation which SOAP output will look like:

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <SomeXmlDocument></SomeXmlDocument>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And SomeXmlDocument means here any XML document defined in runtime. 
The problem now CXF always puts predefined name from WSDL. 
I'll show on examples:

I'm using following command: `wsdl2java.bat -fe jaxws21 -d gen -exsh true -verbose file.wsdl`

If I use wsdl:

```
  <xs:complexType name="CIMObjectType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" processContents="lax"/> 
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="CIMObject" type="tns:CIMObjectType"/>

  <wsdl:message name="GetResponseMessage">
     <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:CIMObject"/>
  </wsdl:message>
```

The output looks like:

```
<soap:Body>
  <ns8:CIMObject>
    <XXX>
      <DeviceID>XXX:YYY</DeviceID>
    </XXX>
  </ns8:CIMObject>
</soap:Body>
```

If I use:

```
  <xs:complexType name="CIMObjectType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" processContents="lax"/> 
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="CIMObject" type="tns:CIMObjectType"/>

  <wsdl:message name="GetResponseMessage">
     <wsdl:part name="Body" type="tns:CIMObjectType"/>
  </wsdl:message>
```

Output looks like:

```
<soap:Body>
  <Body>
    <XXX>
      <DeviceID>XXX:YYY</DeviceID>
    </XXX>
  </Body>
</soap:Body>
```

But I need:

```
<soap:Body>
    <XXX>
      <DeviceID>XXX:YYY</DeviceID>
    </XXX>
</soap:Body>
```

So, the question is: how to modify WSDL to have output I need? Any help is greatly appreciated